# Pure-Css menu 'icon' disappears with bootstrap 3 installed

Tags: css

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstr‌​ap.min.css';
```

I have a an 'overwrite' problem (similar to how bootstrap forces link-style, but you can just use !important). In pure-css you can create responsive menus. 
It has a small 'icon'-like thing (see here: http://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/# resize to small screen first).
I Installed bootstrap, and now simply, the 3-line 'icon' doesn't appear anymore... What could be the problem? Removing the bootstrap link makes it work again... I can't find any style responsible for the 'icon'...

Should i post a jsfiddle? You can simply add bootstrap css with Chrome 'sources' into the css file and save it here: http://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/#...

Thanks in advance

Comment: complete jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: Please add a stacksnippet (edit the question, and click the `< >` icon) - in the stacksnippet, to add bootstrap with `@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';`. A fiddle link is useful too, so we can easily play around with it

Comment: @SkyWookie Here: https://jsfiddle.net/mbg5bmat/ You can see how it is with bootstrap installed, remove the at import at the top to see how it is without it

Comment: @henry i added it, Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! In the end all i had to do was set the property box-sizing to content-box for .menu-link using CSS. Bootstrap automatically sets it to border-box.

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```